# Unions - 2 tables with same column names but different order

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I’m quite new to SQL so please forgive me if this is a novice question.

I have two tables in MS Access, both have the same field names however they are in different orders.
i.e.

```
Table 1’s field order is :
     handle, blockname, officenum, officeowner, building, floor …….
Table 2’s field order is :
     handle, officenum, blockname, floor, building, officeowner ……..
```

My tables are linked to a txt file as they are an output from an autocad drawing.

I’m trying to merge the two tables (eventually I’ll have about 40 different linked tables) into one.

I’ve got so far to as to use UNION ALL which brings them together however the data within the fields is not in the correct field due to the order being different in the two tables.

I’ve got this so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT handle, blockname, officenum, officeowner, building, floor 
FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT handle, officenum, blockname, floor, building, officeowner
FROM Table2;
```

It would be great of someone would be able to assist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can type the fields in any order you want, so make them the same in each part of the query.

Answer (score 2):

you can change column order in select list. In select list columns can be put in any order you want. your query can be

```
SELECT DISTINCT handle, blockname, officenum, officeowner, building, floor 
FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT handle, blockname, officenum, officeowner, building, floor 
FROM Table2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there should be no problem to change order of select, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT handle, blockname, officenum, officeowner, building, floor 
FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT handle, blockname, officenum, officeowner, building, floor
FROM Table2;
```

Union should work fine then.

Comment: Hi, Apologies, that is what i am using at the moment however it still jumbles up the data in the fields. Is there anyway to make the query match the field name sbetween the 2 tables to ensure data ends up in the right field in the query?

Comment: Order of the second 'SELECT' query is changed in my response, in comparison to yours. Which query are you using currently? Is all data in the matching format?